# Make a div take space even if its empty

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I have these divs

if you can see the last one doesn't have a sub value so its empty but the div is not taking a space I tried display: block and it didn't work. how can I make any div take space even if it doesn't have value

card.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../Card/Card.module.css'

function card ({title,value,subValue,date,unit}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.title}>
            {title}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.in}>
            <div className={styles.value}>
            {value}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.unit}>
            {unit}
            </div>
            </div>  
            <div className={styles.subValue}>
            {subValue}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.date}>
            {date}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default card;
```

overview.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '../../components/widgets/Card/Card';
import styles from '../../pages/Overview/Overview.module.css';

const Overview = (props) => {

    const measurment = [
    { title: "Last Blood Pressure", value: "90/60",unit:"mmhg",subValue:"85 BPM",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { title: "Last Body Weight", value: "154",unit:"lb",subValue:"13% Fat",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { title: "Last SpO2", value: "98",unit:"%",subValue:"85 BPM",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    { title: "Last Glucose", value: "200",unit:"mg/dl",subValue:" ",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"}
]

return(
    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent:'flex-end'}} >        
      {
        measurment.map(measurment => {
          return (
            <div  className={styles.cards}>
              <Card
                title={measurment.title}
                value={measurment.value}
                unit = {measurment.unit}
                subValue={measurment.subValue}
                date={measurment.date}
              />
            </div>

          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
};
export default Overview;
```

css:

```
.title {
    color:grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}

.value{
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}

.subValue {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.date {
    color:lightslategrey;
    text-align: right;
    display:flex;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

card.css:

```
.cards{
    margin:1em;
    cursor:pointer;
    min-height: 120px;
    min-width:190px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid #57c0e8;
    padding-left: 0.4rem;
    padding-top: 0.3rem;
    margin-top: 7%;
}
```

my sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/live/Rgw3MK

Comment: Could you share the rendered ("*[mcve]*") HTML and CSS in your post, while it's perhaps useful to see that this is rendered via React, this is a CSS question and so the scripts are largely irrelevant. The HTML that your browser sees (after the scripts have completed) is what matters, and makes it easier for us to offer practical solutions.

Comment: i have shared the complete code isn't better?  and you have access to it and you can edit it in my sandbox

Comment: No, it's not. the 'sandbox' is an external site (questions should be self-contained, though external sites may serve as a bonus) and you've got a lot of code that's irrelevant to the question. The better the question the better the answers (usually), and the less work we have to do to reproduce your problem in an answer the more answers you will (usually) get. It's entirely your choice, and I'm not down-voting or voting to close (though others have, apparently), I am offering what I feel is useful advice to help you get better answers and more help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `min-height` to `.subValue` in CSS.

Comment: i thought about it but i don't want to set a fixed height to the div i want it to take its normal height when it has a content and without

Comment: If an element is empty the browser will see it as `height: 0`. The reason I said `min-height` is so that if the element height grows at any point then it will take on its inherited height.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The name you wanna do that is `placeholder` and you can do it in several ways but I prefer to use pseudo-class that name is `empty`:

```css
.the-div-maybe-vanish:empty {
  height: 30px; /* as what you want */
  width: 30px; /* as what you want */
}
```

This is the range of usage:

[image]

Comment: Just note with the `:placeholder` class that if the element only has whitespace in it (line break, etc), it won't count as empty.

Comment: @JakeParis, thanks for your hint.

Comment: @AmerllicA so i tried giving the subValue an empty property like u said but also didn't work :/ can you try it in the sandbox?